# What HTML elements are recommended semantically for keywords index (in books)?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

What HTML elements are the most appropriate semantically for building markup of [an index (as in publishing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(publishing))? Keyword index usually can be found in technical literature, and while it is clear that page numbers are a bit off here, but let's imagine those are abbreviated chapter numbers wrapped with hyperlinks.

[image: Here is the screenshot of "Index" Appendix with keywords used in a book and their page numbers]

While the screenshot is a bit specific, nevertheless I assume my question is generic enough in its essence.

Comment: Altough you have a real question, stackOverflow is not the place for questions that look for opinion based answers. So it's probably going to be closed and flagged as "primarily opinion-based", as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @CalvinNunes, thanks for the reply. It's a pity to hear, together with the fact that semantics is a bit hard to grasp. Some examples are easier, some are harder. For instance, in my case, I even thought about <ol> (ordered list), because actually keywords are ordered alphabetically. I was thinking about <dfn>, but does not sound like a brilliant idea - AFAIU, only the first occurrence of the word should be marked with that tag. And so on...

Comment: @CalvinNunes I think this is on-topic.  I can open up a screen reader and test definitively whether it reads elements and considers their relationship correctly.  Maybe the question should be edited to remove the "appropriate" question and instead directly ask how to get assistive reading technology to understand the relation of elements in this instance.  The answer is likely a `<dl>` as the answer below states.

Comment: Additionally, I think the OP should include their notes about the elements that they have already tried and why they don't correctly create the desired relationship.

Comment: IMHO the *not opinion-based* rule should be left for stuff like "what's the best language". Picking semantic tags is a perfectly legit problem and it's difficult to get too opinionated without being objectively wrong, as in "use `<img>`". Some times it's even possible to link official documents with recommendations.

Comment: @noomorph, the accepted answer is good, but it's best to put each individual page reference in its own `<dd>` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<dl>` (description list) would be the best fit for marking up an index.

```html
<dl>
  <dt>absolute URLs</dt>
  <dd>79</dd>

  <dt>accessibility</dt>
  <dd>7
    <dl>
      <dt>alt text</dt>
      <dd>99, 272, 480</dd>
      <dt>contrast</dt>
      <dd>253, 420</dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
  
  <dt>acronyms</dt>
  <dd>53</dd>
</dl>
```

According to [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element):

> The `dl` element represents an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups (a description list). [...] Name-value groups may be **terms and definitions**, metadata topics and values, questions and answers, or any other groups of **name-value data**.

You can think of each keyword in the index as a "term/name," and each page number as a "definition/value."

Comment: I agree with this answer. However the individual page references should each be in their own `<dd>` element.